# Capture Approval Email reply with Apex

Tags: apex-email-service, approval-process

In an Approval Process, with email approval activated, when an approver replied by email, is it possible to capture that email and do additional processing with Apex?

What I want is to forward the email sent to SF for Approval to a sepcific email address. The user is currently doing a CC when it's doing the approval but want to enforce that email sending.